# Avoiding $onlyActive boolean parameter

Tags: php, methods, laravel-4, boolean

I recently started using phpmd to detect bad coding practices and fix them. My project uses the Laravel 4 php framework and I implement a repository pattern.

So I have a class called `EloquentProductRepository` which interacts with the product tables in my database. Some methods like the `all()` method have a boolean parameter called `$onlyActive`. When true it only fetches the active products, otherwise all are returned.

Phpmd tells me that boolean parameters are a certain sign of violation of the single responsibility pattern. So I did some reading and agree that booleans should probably be avoided. Now my question is how should I refactor this with regards to maintainability, readability and extendibility?

The method is rather simple and looks as follows

```
/**
 * Fetches all products
 *
 * @param boolean $onlyActive Flag for only returning active products
 * @return Collection
 */
public function all($onlyActive = true)
{
    if ($onlyActive)
    {
        return $this->model->where('active', true)->get();
    }

    return $this->model->all();
}
```

I see 2 options. One is using an $options array instead with a key 'include_inactive'. The other option is creating 2 methods. `all()` and `allWithInactive()`. I currently have 3 methods using the $onlyActive boolean so the last option would add 3 methods to my class which might make the class rather large on methods. (phpmd prefers classes to have no more than 10 public methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two different functions - so this is how I would do it

```
public function getAll()
{
    return $this->model->all();
}


public function getOnlyActive()
{
    return $this->model->where('active', true)->get();
}
```

Note the function names - `getAll()` does exactly that - ALL records, no exceptions. The `getOnlyActive()` does exactly that - only active records - there is no "all" in that function name, because it doesnt get "all".

Comment: I'll use this approach. Seems the most clean one. Don't expect any more options for now.